# I keep getting a BUILD FAILED error when trying to create a React Native application.

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am completely new to React Native. I followed the instructions from the Get Started page for React Native. These are the commands I've run so far:

-brew install node
-brew install watchman
-npm install -g react-native-cli

I created my project using this command:
-react-native init AwesomeProject

I tried to run my app using:
-react-native run-ios

Then I get an the build error. Even though the simulator opens up, the app does not open up. Please help.

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following commands produced analyzer issues:
    Analyze /Users/LuisRizo/Documents/Web\ Projects/React/newProject/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGNodeList.c
    Analyze /Users/LuisRizo/Documents/Web\ Projects/React/newProject/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.c
(2 commands with analyzer issues)

The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Install\ Third\ Party /Users/LuisRizo/Documents/Web\ Projects/React/newProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/double-conversion.build/Script-190EE32F1E6A43DE00A8543A.sh
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/newProject.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/newProject.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

Comment: There's a bunch of issues on the React Native Github around the `":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist` error. To narrow down the issue, could you post your: node, npm, and react-native versions as well as your `package.json` file. Also, check to see if anything is running on the default port used by React Native which I believe is 8081.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. 
node v8.2.1
npm 5.3.0
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.46.4

Comment: I tried to see if anything is running on port 8081 using command "$ sudo lsof -i :8081" but I am getting "-bash: $: command not found". 

Also, how can I find my package.json file so I can post it here?

Comment: Remove the `$` from your command and it should work. If this is not the issue, you can look [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7308) for some potential solutions.

Comment: @Igrizo Your `package.json` file should be in the root folder of the react native project. It was created when you ran `react-native init AwesomeProject`.

Comment: I think i got it 
{
 "name": "albums",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
  "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
  "test": "jest"
 },
 "dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.0.0-alpha.6",
  "react-native": "0.46.4"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
  "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
  "babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",
  "jest": "20.0.4",
  "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
 },
 "jest": {
  "preset": "react-native"
 }
}
@MichaelCheng

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's an update. I completely uninstalled everything (watchman, node, homebrew, npm, etc).

Then I started from scratch using the Quick Start guide from React Native. I installed node by downloading the zip from their website. Then followed by these commands:

npm install -g create-react-native-app

create-react-native-app AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject

npm start

npm run ios

During the first run, I got the same errors as before. Then I read that "reset content and settings" in the Simulator menu would help. I did this. My simulator restarted. Then i ran -"npm run ios" again, and it booted up without any errors. Now I'm up and running. Not sure exactly which part corrected my errors but these were the steps I took.